# MATCH Query Issues after switching to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Hello guys I was just moved to a new server running MariaDB and now it seems my fulltext searches are not working.

For example...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Model = "CR-V";
```

works.

```
SELECT *, MATCH (Model) AGAINST ("CR-V") as score FROM table WHERE MATCH (Model) AGAINST ("CR-V") ORDER BY score DESC;
```

does not return anything.

This used to work perfectly fine in my old server, now it's not. Any help would be appreciated.